# build kernel module do_softirq() undefined

Tags: linux-kernel

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int example_init(void) {
        printk("<1>EXAMPLE: init\n");
        do_softirq();
        return 0;
}

static void example_exit(void) {
        printk("<1>EXAMPLE: exit\n");
}

module_init(example_init);
module_exit(example_exit);
```

Build the module on ubuntu 20.04. I got an error.

```
ERROR: "do_softirq" undefined!
```

Any suggestion how to fix this error?

Comment: As noted by @user2699113 in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202199/3440745), the function `do_softirq` is **internal** for the Linux kernel implementation. What do you want to **achieve** by calling this function? Without that information we hardly can help you. (*Random* picking a function and calling it in the code is NOT a *programming*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to run this procedure? It is **internal** kernel function which is invocated in particular circumstances - among others in some thread. You shouldn't invoke it from kernel's module.

To compile you example module you can try to export in kernel this symbol - like this:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(do_softirq);
```

in softirq.c file but it is not recommended. Try to look for tasklets, workqueue interface or kthreads instead.